# Question about “change of variable” of a parabolic function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> If $\varphi$ is parabolic then $\varphi$ is conjugate to a transaltion in $\Pi^+$: There exists $B \in \mathbb{R}$ with $B \neq 0$ such that the element of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Pi^+)$ corresponding to $\varphi$ is conjugate to $\psi$, where $\psi(z) = z + B \ \ (z \in \Pi^+)$.

Proof:

> Suppose that if $\varphi$ is either parabolic or hyperbolic. We switch to the
> upper half-plane: We may assume that $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(\Pi^+)$, $\varphi$ has no fixed point in $\Pi^+$ and either one or two fixed points on $\partial_\infty\Pi^+$. In either case we may make
> a change of variables (using an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Pi^+)$) so that $\varphi(\infty) = \infty $ [...]

We say that $b$ is equivalent to $a$ after a “change of variables” given by $c$ when $b = c^{-1}ac$ where $a,b,c\in G, G$ is a group.

My question is: How we make that change of variable with elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Pi^+)$?